# Extract the list of title from div class

Tags: php, html, screen-scraping

I created a function that uses CURL to connect to a website and get the tv listing for the day. I would like to get the `div` class tags from the html source as well.

Here is what I'm using right now:

```
<?php

function get_shows($channel_id, DateTime $dt, $skip_finished = true) {

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
      CURLOPT_USERAGENT => '',
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 5,
   ));

   $date = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
   $tz = $dt->getTimezone();

   $now = new DateTime('now', $tz);
   $today = $now->format('Y-m-d');

   $shows = array();  
   for($p=0;$p<=6;$p++) {
      $url = 'http://www.example.com/channels/tvlistings?date=' . $date;
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      echo $url;
   }
}
?>
```

There are six class that come with the same name in the html source where you can see:

```
<div class="rowChannel">
        <div class="colTimes">
             <span class="title">some information 1</span><span class="desc"><p>description goes here</p></span>


<div class="rowChannel">
        <div class="colTimes">

            <span class="title">some information 2</span><span class="desc"><p>description goes here</p></span>


<div class="rowChannel">
        <div class="colTimes">

            <span class="title">some information 3</span><span class="desc"><p>description goes here</p></span>


<div class="rowChannel">
        <div class="colTimes">

            <span class="title">some information 4</span><span class="desc"><p>description goes here</p></span>

<div class="rowChannel">
        <div class="colTimes">

            <span class="title">some information 5</span><span class="desc"><p>description goes here</p></span>

<div class="rowChannel">
        <div class="colTimes">

            <span class="title">some information 6</span><span class="desc"><p>description goes here</p></span>
```

What I want is to extract the list of title and description from the second class ahead of the first one and ignore the others.

Like this:

```
<div class="rowChannel">
        <div class="colTimes">

            <span class="title">some information 2</span><span class="desc"><p>description goes here</p></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the HTML file is [well formed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_element) (the one provided in your example is not) you can use [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) to extract the information you want.

For example:

```
$body = '<root>
   <div class="rowChannel">
      <div class="colTimes">
         <span class="title">some information 1</span>
         <span class="desc">
            <p>description goes here</p>
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="rowChannel">
      <div class="colTimes">
         <span class="title">some information 2</span>
         <span class="desc">
            <p>description goes here</p>
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>
</root>';

 // clear any whitespaces between elements
 $data = preg_replace("/>\s+</", "><", $body);

 $dom = new DOMDocument();
 @$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($data, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
 $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
 $elements = $xpath->query("//div[@class='colTimes']");
 $listings = [];
 foreach ($elements as $i => $element) {
      $title = $element->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
      $desc = $element->childNodes->item(1)->nodeValue;

      $listings[] = [
           'title' => $title,
           'desc' => $desc
      ];
 }
```

Comment: thank you very much for that but i'm using curl so can you please change your code and use mine instead to allow me to get the title and description from the second div class?

Comment: curl is used to **fetch** your data from the remote resource. `DOMDocument` and `DOMXpath` classes are used to **parse** the data the way you ask for. It's 2 different things. Therefore, you cannot parse using curl.

Comment: In your code just after your `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);` add the following function call: `$body=curl_exec($ch);`This way you will receive the body of your html document. Afterwards apply the code provided.

Comment: thank you, do you know how i can get the url tags called `<a class="prog" href="/setanta/tvlistinginfo/71222">` to open the page to parse the data I want when i look for the tags called `<div class="channel">` from the rows?

Comment: This can be done similarly using XPath. However it is out of the scope of the original question, so you should either create a new question or (even better) try to experiment a little with the solution given above. Keep in mind that if the answer solved your problem you should accept the answer as correct so that other users can benefit from it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as per your requirement:
$file_contents = curl_exec($ch); //get the page contents
preg_match($s_searchFor, $file_contents, $matches); //match the element
$file_contents = $matches[1];

Comment: thank you but there is a problem. It won't show the title and desc in the php page. There is something wrong with your code I guess?

Comment: I gave you an idea only now, you have to manipulate the code as per your requirement

Comment: yeah but it doesn't get the title and desc I want as your code doesn't work that good as i have tried it.

Comment: What did you get in file contents variable, after checking it may be i can help you out.